# Casting IList<[ModelObject]> to IList<EntityObject>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Can I cast a IList of a specific Model Class to a IList of the class EntityObject in an MVC 3 .Net c# project? The specific Model Class if defined as subclass of the EntityObject class. When I trie the cast I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GesDis.Models.TiposCursosCEF]' to
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject]'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of co-variance. That is to say, that just because `B` derives from `A`, and you can assign `A a = new B()`, it doesn't mean that you can assign `T<B>` to `T<A>`. Those are just two different generic types and the assignment doesn't work.

Instead you need to do something like this:

```
IList<EntityObject> entityObjects = modelObjects.Cast<EntityObject>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if you could cast it you could do something like that:

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}
class SomeOther : Base {}

var list = new List<Derived>();
var baseList = (IList<Base>)list;

baseList.Add(new SomeOther()); // oops, add SomeOther to a List<Derived>
```